# How to set custom style to sementic ui components, reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

Here is my model for login page, the form fields have gained the full width of the modal. I want to set a margin of `10px` around each input field.

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button, Input, Modal } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Modal dimmer="blurring" open={true} size={"medium"}>
      <Modal.Header>Login</Modal.Header>
      <Input fluid placeholder="Username" icon="user" />

      <Input fluid placeholder="Password" icon="key" type="password" />
      <Modal.Actions>
        <Button
          positive
          icon="checkmark"
          labelPosition="right"
          content="Submit"
        />
      </Modal.Actions>
    </Modal>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is straight forward. But I couldn't find the documentation. I simply added styles directly to the component. it worked.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button, Input, Modal } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

const inlineStyle = {
    input : {
      margin: '10px',
    }
  };
function App() {
  return (
    <Modal dimmer="blurring" open={true} size={"medium"}>
      <Modal.Header>Login</Modal.Header>
      <Input fluid placeholder="Username" icon="user" style={inlineStyle.input}/>

      <Input fluid placeholder="Password" icon="key" type="password" style={inlineStyle.input}/>
      <Modal.Actions>
        <Button
          positive
          icon="checkmark"
          labelPosition="right"
          content="Submit"
        />
      </Modal.Actions>
    </Modal>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```